# Function overload errors

Tags: python

```
class sınıf():
   
    def area(r):
        return (22.0/7)*r*2
    def area(a,b):
        return (22*5)

print(sınıf.area(5))
print(sınıf.area(5,2))
```

```
     print(sınıf.area(5))
TypeError: area() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

How do we solve this problem? missing 1 required positional argument

Comment: Python does not support function overloading.  GIve it a different name, or optional arguments: eg, def area(x, b=None):

Comment: Python does not support function overloading, so generally you don't. You can make `b` default to None, and then check if `b is None` and do the other version. You can also use singledispatch _if_ a single argument only differs by type: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch

Comment: Note: you can use math.pi. And `r*2` is not r-squared.